# Restlet URL/path pattern mismapping

Tags: java, rest, uri, restlet, url-pattern

I'm developing a REST API using Restlet.

So far everything has been working just fine. However, I now encountered an issue with the `Router` mapping of URL to `ServerResource`.

I've got the following scenario:

- GET `/car` returns a list of all cars
- GET `/car/{id}` returns details about the car with id 1
- GET `/car/advancedsearch?param1=test` should run a search across all cars with some parameters

The first two calls work without any problems. If I try to hit the third call though, the Restlet `Router` somehow maps it to the second one instead. How can I tell Restlet to instead use the third case?

My mapping is defined as follows:

```
router.attach("/car",                CarListResource.class);
router.attach("/car/{id}",           CarResource.class);
router.attach("/car/advancedsearch", CarSearchResource.class);
```

`CarSearchResource` is never invoked, but rather the request ends up in `CarResource`.

The router's default matching mode is set to `Template.MODE_EQUALS`, so that can't be causing it.

Does anyone have any further suggestions how I could fix it?

---

*Please don't suggest to use `/car` with the parameters instead, as there's already another kind of search in place on that level. Also, I'm not in control of the API structure, so it has to remain as it is.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by simply reordering the `attach` statements:

```
router.attach("/car/advancedsearch", CarSearchResource.class);
router.attach("/car",                CarListResource.class);
router.attach("/car/{id}",           CarResource.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `.setMatchingQuery(true);` to that rout in order it to recognize that it is with a query at the end of it.

```
    Router router = (Router) super.createInboundRoot();
    TemplateRoute route1 = router.attach("/car/advancedsearch?{query_params}", MyResource.class);
    route1.setMatchingQuery(true);
    return router;
```

Mind that this pattern is with the exact specific order that you have determined in the route i.e. `advancedsearch` comes first and `query_params` comes after

Comment: I did not have to do that for the main `/car` path and that one uses parameters as well. Also, it has to be `/car/advancedsearch`, not `/advancedsearch`.

Comment: I've also tried this now, but the result is the same.

Comment: its only true for query form

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. `/car` and `/car/advancedsearch` *both* have query parameters in my case. The first works just fine now, the second doesn't.